# Efficient max-odd-factor sum of numbers in range 1 to N

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm searching for an efficient algorithm to add the max odd factors of a range of numbers [1..N], see this example:

```
input: 9
output: 31 (sum of max odd factors of: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

The following table shows what is considered the *max odd factor* of a number and also their sum:

| Number | Factors | Max odd factor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **1** | 1 |
| 2 | **1**, 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1, **3** | 3 |
| 4 | **1**, 2, 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1, **5** | 5 |
| 6 | 1, 2, **3**, 6 | 3 |
| 7 | 1, **7** | 7 |
| 8 | **1**, 2, 4, 8 | 1 |
| 9 | 1, 3, **9** | 9 |
|  | **Sum of max odd factors** | **31** |

I've tried this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 9;
        var result = Enumerable.Range(1, n).Sum(s => greatestOddFactor(s));
        Console.Write(result);
    }

    static int greatestOddFactor(int n)
    {
        if (isOdd(n)) return n;

        int pow_2 = (int)(Math.Sqrt(n));
        int i = 1;

        while (i <= pow_2)
        {
            int fac_2 = (2 * i);
            if (n % fac_2 == 0)
            {
                if ((n / fac_2) % 2 == 1)
                {
                    return (n / fac_2);
                }
            }
            i += 1;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    static bool isOdd(int n) => !(n % 2 == 0);
}
```

But the code shown performs poorly on big inputs.

How to make code/program/algorithm that can efficiently handle inputs of around ***2 billions***?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. 
seems like a typical homework question to me. can you please share what you've tried and researched so far? we'll gladly help if you're stuck somewhere, but you should first attempt to solve the task on your own - and be able to describe your efforts. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I also found `1333333335334181226` with my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Start with pen and paper

If you do some research with paper and pen, you'll see that the sum of the maximum odd factors can be decomposed into the sum of sums of ranges over odd numbers. Each line in the following list shows the iterative reduction of an even to an odd number (each arrows is a division by two):

```
 1
 2 → 1
 3
 4 → 2 → 1
 5
 6 → 3
 7
 8 → 4 → 2 → 1
 9
10 → 5
11
12 → 6 → 3
13
14 → 7
15
```

We know that the sum of a range of odd numbers can be written as a square. This image illustrates the relation between odd numbers and squares: consecutive areas differ by an odd number. IOW as to get from a given square to its size neighbor, you have to add twice its edge plus one for the corner.

[image: relation between odd numbers and squares]

So above list can can be written as a sum of squares with `log₂(n)` components:

```
 1 =>  1 = 1
 2 =>  2 = 1  + 1
 3 =>  5 = 2² + 1  + 
 4 =>  6 = 2² + 1  + 1
 5 => 11 = 3² + 1  + 1
 6 => 14 = 3² + 2² + 1
 7 => 21 = 4² + 2² + 1
 8 => 22 = 4² + 2² + 1  + 1
 9 => 31 = 5² + 2² + 1  + 1
10 => 36 = 5² + 3² + 1  + 1
11 => 47 = 6² + 3² + 1  + 1
12 => 50 = 6² + 3² + 2² + 1
13 => 63 = 7² + 3² + 2² + 1
14 => 70 = 7² + 4² + 2² + 1
15 => 85 = 8² + 4² + 2² + 1
```

#### Don't be afraid to experiment

Looking onto the square roots in above list, I had to find a way of representing them in terms of the input. For example, to get `8`, `4`, `2`, `1` from `15` the same way as to get `4`, `2`, `1`, `1` from `8`. It's obvious that here is integer division by two at work but is has to be combined with the addition of the right number(s).

#### Create some code

After getting some idea of how a mathematical approach could look like, I tried a prototype function. I checked the results against the ones I gained by the original approach (after fixing the OP's `greatestOddFactor` function, see *Remarks*). Here is the program I came up with:

```
using System;

namespace max_odd_fac_sum
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long n = 2_000_000_000;
            Console.WriteLine($"{n} --> {sumOddFactors(n)}");
        }

        static long sumOddFactors(long n)
        {
            long res = 0;
            long a = 1;
            while (n >= a)
            {
                var v = (n + a) / (a << 1);
                res += v * v;
                a <<= 1;
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

... and its output:

```
2000000000 --> 1333333333334181226
```

#### Review this code

After checking out [Damien's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67707914/2932052) I polished my function a bit, so it's easier to read:

```
        static long SumOddFactorsPolished(long n)
        {
            long res = 1;
            while (n > 1)
            {
                var v = (n + 1) >> 1;
                res += v * v;
                n >>= 1;
            }
            return res;
        }
```

#### *Concluding remarks*

##### Your greatestOddFactor function

Here is an improved and fixed<sup>1)</sup> version for `greatestOddFactor` but as is now obvious, we will never be able to optimize the performance of an iterative approach to get comparable efficiency to any of the *O(log(n))* approaches shown.

```
static long greatestOddFactor(int n)
{
    while ((n & 1) == 0)
    {
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return n;
}
```

<sup>1)</sup>  <sub>[Your implementation of `greatestOddFactor`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/67698941/5) has a serious problem that remains invisible for inputs below 48, but from then on consistently returns wrong results. For `48` it returns `1` instead of the correct `3` (`48 = 4² * 3`). This is due to the limitation of the factors to `sqrt(n)` which may help when factoring into primes but which is totally wrong for the given task.</sub>

##### Binary representation and operations

You may know that integers can be expressed using only two digits `0` and `1`, this representation is called binary. For humans who are mostly dealing with decimals the binary system may feel very strange, but one observation of our every-day live can be found even in this system: multiplication with (and dividing by) the *base* is easy. In decimal we observe that multiplying by 10 `123 * 10 = 1230` can be done by appending a zero digit `0` at the right end of `123` because `10` is the base of the decimal system. In analogy, in the binary system, we multiply by `2` (`10₂` or [`0b_10`](https://airbrake.io/blog/csharp/digit-separators-reference-returns-and-binary-literals) in C# syntax) by appending a `0` to the right end of the binary representation. Dividing without remainder is done be removing the rightmost digit in both systems.

My solution uses some binary operations which work on the binary representation of integers:

- binary and `&` resulting in binary `1` if present in both operands
- shift left (`<<`) appends a 0 to the right of the binary representation
- shift right (`>>`) cuts the rightmost digit of the binary representation

The following table shows some small numbers in binary representation together with the operations that were used in my answer (decimal representations given in parentheses):

| Number `n` | `n & 0b_0001` | `n << 1` | `n >> 1` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `0b_0000` (0) | `0b_0000` (0) | `0b_0000` (0) | `0b_0000` (0) |
| `0b_0001` (1) | `0b_0001` (1) | `0b_0010` (2) | `0b_0000` (0) |
| `0b_0010` (2) | `0b_0000` (0) | `0b_0100` (4) | `0b_0001` (1) |
| `0b_0011` (3) | `0b_0001` (1) | `0b_0110` (6) | `0b_0001` (1) |
| `0b_0100` (4) | `0b_0000` (0) | `0b_1000` (8) | `0b_0010` (2) |
| `0b_0101` (5) | `0b_0001` (1) | `0b_1010` (10) | `0b_0010` (2) |
| `0b_0110` (6) | `0b_0000` (0) | `0b_1100` (12) | `0b_0011` (3) |
| `0b_0111` (7) | `0b_0001` (1) | `0b_1110` (14) | `0b_0011` (3) |

Comment: thank you very much, you are very awesome.

Comment: @ridone06 You are welcome. An interesting detail to make your question even more attractive would be to add some information about the actual purpose of such calculation. Was it "just a test" or are there practical applications for it?

Answer (score 1):

A recursion implementation provides a simple O(log(n)) solution.

Let us call `f(n)` the sum.

Then by using the fact that `1 + 3 + 5 + ... + 2p+1 = (p+1)*(p+1)`, we can directly conclude that

```
f(n) = f(n/2) + a*a, with a = (n+1)/2 (integer division)
```

This last expression comes from the fact that if `n` is even, then the max odd factor of `n` is equal to the max odd factor of `n/2`